# Master/Detail Flow inside of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, master-detail

I have a app that uses ActionBar and Fragment to show several different views in the app. So far I am only showing either a list of items, a photo, a web view... but I want to go further and show in the Fragment a Master/Detail Flow, so that I can have a ListView and DetailView. This is so far a sample code

```
    // ActionBar
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // create new tabs and and set up the titles of the tabs
    ActionBar.Tab mFindTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_find));
    ActionBar.Tab mChatTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_chat));
    ActionBar.Tab mMeetTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_meet));
    ActionBar.Tab mPartyTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_party));

    // create the fragments
    Fragment mFindFragment = new FindFragment();
    Fragment mChatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    Fragment mMeetFragment = new MeetFragment();
    Fragment mPartyFragment = new PartyFragment();

    // bind the fragments to the tabs - set up tabListeners for each tab
    mFindTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mFindFragment,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mChatTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mChatFragment,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mMeetTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mMeetFragment,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mPartyTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mPartyFragment,
            getApplicationContext()));

    // add the tabs to the action bar
    actionbar.addTab(mFindTab);
    actionbar.addTab(mChatTab);
    actionbar.addTab(mMeetTab);
    actionbar.addTab(mPartyTab);
```

How can I create the Master/Detail Flow so that when touch on the corresponding action bar.tab it is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can create stubs for this in the 'New' Menu?

The menu selections: File>New>Android Activity>Master / Detail Flow

I suggest you create an example using this Wizard, and then use it to understand how everything works (this will give you code that uses the proper patterns, and has implemented all the correct code standards).

Comment: I think his main problem will be the backwards functionality and maintaining consistency. If that is the case the auto-generated code will not help him.